# How do I extend the style of a button?

Tags: android

I'm creating a button in an activity:

```
Button contactButton = new Button(this, null, R.style.ContactButton);
contactButton.setText(contactName);
contactsView.addView(contactButton);
```

With the corresponding style:

```
<style name="ContactButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"> 
</style>
```

I'm trying to get it to use the ContactButton style, extending the Widget.Button style, so that I can keep style properties in one place without having to redefine the whole button (9-patch background et al.)

However I cannot find any way for it to inherit the default button style. The result of the above always appears to be a default TextView.

The closest I've got is passing buttonStyle into the Button constructor, which gives me back the default button look but of course I can't override it this way:

```
Button contactButton = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
```

So, any ideas how to accomplish this?

**Update:**

This seems to be a [bug in the View class](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683), which explains why `new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyle)` works and `new Button(this, null, android.R.style.Widget_Button)` doesn't, although the former is just a reference to the latter.

I'm only running into this bug because I'm creating the Buttons programmatically, setting the `style` attribute in XML works fine.

I'd still like to know if there's a simple workaround which still lets me use the style system.

Comment: Have you tried inflating the button from XML rather than creating it pragmatically?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Can you create a factory class and have it return you new instances of a redefined object?

```
Class ButtonFactory(){
    public Button getStyledButton(String name){
        Button styledButton = new Button();
        styledButton.setText(name);
        // do stuff to button
        return styledButton
    }
}
```

Add this in Your activity.

```
onCreate(..){
   ButtonFactory builder = new ButtonFactory();
   Button styledButton = builder.getStyledButton();
}
```

Comment: Yes modifying the button instance directly does work, but I'm hoping to use the styles system to keep it nicely separated.